# Is there a way in css to have something be 100% of window size when its container is only 25%?

Tags: css

I'm trying to make a picture menu that when clicked has the other options slide away and show the entire image of the option clicked.
The images are lined up and I'm using overflow hidden to hide the parts that I don't want shown until their clicked.
The animation works fine but if the browser window is larger then the image width then it leaves white space where the image runs out of room. I can set the image to a new width during the transition but it makes the transition look strange as the size of the image is changing too which I don't want.

Is there a way to set something to the size of the window even if its container isn't that size?

http://jsfiddle.net/539Y9/ - 
A basic jsfiddle is here. Its harder to tell since I don't have images and you'll probably need to look at dev tools to see the size of the divs but I want those divs to be 100% and hidden by its parent container.

HTML:

```
<div id="imageMenu">
  <ul>
    <li class="imageMenuItem"><div id='image1'></div></li>
    <li class="imageMenuItem"><div id='image2'></div></li>
    <li class="imageMenuItem"><div id='image3'></div></li>
    <li class="imageMenuItem"><div id='image4'></div></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#imageMenu ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#imageMenu li {
  text-decoration: none;
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  z-index: 0;
}

#image1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: red;
}

#image2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 25px;
  background: green;
}

#image3 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: blue;
}

#image4 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what animation you're referring to, but you can use [the `vw` unit](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths) to size the element relative to the viewport instead of its parent.

> The viewport-percentage lengths are relative to the size of the initial containing block. When the height or width of the initial containing block is changed, they are scaled accordingly.

The *initial containing block* here is the root element in your document, not the element's parent.

```css
#image1, #image2, #image3, #image4 {
    width: 100vw;
}
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/539Y9/1/) - notice how the yellow `div` element at the end stretches by the same width as the entire result pane? All your `div` elements here are doing this but are being covered by the next one along.

Here's a [**second demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/539Y9/2/) where I've added a hover effect to your `div` elements to show how this works.

Comment: @Todd the `vw` unit works on all modern browsers apart from Opera Mini. They even work on IE9. http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units

Comment: They do not work on IE8, which has twice global usage of versions 9 and 10 combined according to caniuse.com. I would call that a no go, especially for something fundamental like a navigation.

Comment: Understood, but still much less than stable. I'd still avoid using it for now without a fallback. Support seems flaky, if not buggy. Don't get me wrong, I get all hand-wavy about these awesome new features too, but like fallbacks until full-ish marketshare support.

Answer (score 2):

Just specify `width: 400%` on the images.

Since you split the original width into 4 by using 25%, you can get the original width at the child element again if you multiply its width by 4. Which is 400%.

Comment: This works but when i resize them they behave a bit strage so I've chosen the other answer. Thanks for you help :)